# Define php var after textbox

Tags: php, html, variables

So I have a variable well defined in a php page and I'm using it in an HTML page using include.
I am currently building a page where I can change the Var ( because it's a long text, more than one actually, and to change them it will be nice to have a page with a layout just for that) so I'm using a textbox and a submit button just like this:

```
<?php
$titre= 'Bienvenido a PARIS EXPERT LIMOUSINE !  ' ;
?>

<form method="post">
 Titre: <input name="titre" type="text" id="titre" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($titre); ?>" size="50" maxlength="50">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$titre = $_POST['titre'];
echo($titre);
}
?>
```

The problem is that in the echo it shows the new text but if I do a refresh it will show the old one...
any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Added extra fields and data handler.** See extra code below original answer.

---

Here is some code I came up with to write content to a file.

Note: To add to the file with content written one under the other, use the `a` or `a+` switch.

To create and write content to file and overwrite previous content, use the `w` switch.

This method uses the [**fwrite()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) function.

(tested)

Added to OP's code: `action="write.php"`

**FORM**

```
<?php

$titre= 'Bienvenido a PARIS EXPERT LIMOUSINE !  ' ;
?>

<form method="post" action="write.php">
Titre: <input name="titre" type="text" id="titre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['titre'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['titre']); } 
else echo htmlspecialchars($titre); ?>" size="50" maxlength="50">


<input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

**PHP write to file handler** (write.php)

This example uses the `w` switch.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$titre = $_POST['titre'];
echo($titre);
}
?>

<?php

$filename = "output.txt"; #Must CHMOD to 666 or 644
$text = $_POST['titre']; # Form must use POST. if it uses GET, use the line below:
// $text = $_GET['titre']; #POST is the preferred method

$fp = fopen ($filename, "w" ); # w = write to the file only, create file if it does not exist, discard existing contents
if ($fp) {
    fwrite ($fp, $text. "\n");
    fclose ($fp);
    echo ("File written");
}
else {
    echo ("File was not written");
}

?>
```

---

---

**EDIT: Added extra fields and data handler.**

Extra fields can be added, and must be followed in the same fashion in the file handler.

**NEW FORM with extra fields**

File data example: `test | email@example.com | 123-456-7890`

```
<?php

$titre= 'Bienvenido a PARIS EXPERT LIMOUSINE !  ' ;
?>

<form method="post" action="write.php">
Titre: <input name="titre" type="text" id="titre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['titre'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['titre']); } 
else echo htmlspecialchars($titre); ?>" size="50" maxlength="50">

<br>
Email: <input name="email" size="50" maxlength="50">

<br>
Telephone: <input name="telephone" size="50" maxlength="50">


<input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$titre = $_POST['titre'];
echo($titre);
}
?>
```

**PHP write to file handler**

```
<?php

$titre = $_POST['titre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$data = "$titre | $email | $telephone";

$fp = fopen("data.txt", "a"); // a-add append or w-write overwrite

if ($fp) {
    fwrite ($fp, $data. "\n");
    fclose ($fp);
    echo ("File written successfully.");
}

else{
  echo "FAILED";
}

?>
```

Comment: it works.. however is it possible to have several vars in the same text file?

Comment: @Alpha Sure. It depends what vars you would like to have. What would you like to do?

Comment: I have 9 var and they should do exactly the same as the $titre..
ofc I'll have 9 textboxes ans 9 buttons

Comment: @Alpha There are two ways to go about this, pre-define each variable < (more control), or use a `foreach`.

Comment: @Alpha Edited my answer with extra options. You will have to add/edit your own fields. (tested)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Titre: <input name="titre" type="text" id="titre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['titre'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['titre']); } 
else echo htmlspecialchars($titre); ?>" size="50" maxlength="50">
```

If you need to keep your value for ever, you should store it in a database or save it in a file (could be .txt).

**[EDIT]**

Here is the code for .txt solution (you first create a file.txt in the same folder):

```
<?php
$file = 'file.txt';

$lines  = file("file.txt");
if (!isset($lines[0])) {$titre='Bienvenido a PARIS EXPERT LIMOUSINE !  ';}
else {$titre=$lines[0];}
?>
<form method="post">
 Titre: <input name="titre" type="text" id="titre" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['titre'])){echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['titre']); } 
else echo htmlspecialchars($titre); ?>" size="50" maxlength="50">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo($_POST['titre']);
$titre = $_POST['titre']."\n".$titre;
file_put_contents($file, $titre);
}

?>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If I refresh after changing the value the old value comes up.. He doesn't keep the new one..

Comment: It works!! thanks...
BTW is it possible to have several variables inside the same .txt file?

Comment: Yes, Check my edit :) Now it keeps all previous values in file.txt and displays last one

Comment: If you would like yo do same thing with other variables than titre, you can either put each var in a separate file or store all vars in the same file with a specific delimiter (newline or ; etc...);

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if(!($titre = file_get_contents("filename.txt"))){
  $titre= 'Bienvenido a PARIS EXPERT LIMOUSINE !  ' ;
}

?>

<form method="post">
  Titre: <input name="titre" type="text" id="titre" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($titre); ?>" size="50" maxlength="50">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $titre = $_POST['titre'];
  if(@file_put_contents("filename.txt", $titre))){
    echo 'Success - var stored.';
  } else { echo 'Some error.'; }
  echo($titre);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is normal because you're showing the new content upon form submission. When you refresh the page, unless you tell it to send the `POST` data again with the refresh (which the browser asks you for confirmation), your form (and hence the input field) will have nothing in.

Comment: But I need to save the new value.. not only save for the moment but change it 4ever..

Comment: @ImaneFateh is right. if you need to store the value, then you need to store it for later use, which is not possible through HTML

Comment: @ImaneFateh I like the idea of a file.. but what type of file and how?

Comment: You can use .txt file, use the function file_put_contents()

Comment: @ImaneFateh or the OP can use `fwrite()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: @Alpha If you're going to choose to write to a file, you will need to know one basic thing. Using `w` switch will write to file but will overwrite previous content. And using the `a` switch will add/append to the file.

Comment: @Alpha Have a look at my answer for an example to write to a file. I hope this serves you well, cheers.